# Work done separating parallel plates

Tags: energy, work, potential-energy, capacitance

You charge up a capacitor, disconnect it, then push the plates apart. d increases, so the potential energy increases, so change in U is positive. Because w=-u, work should be negative. But my physics teacher said it's positive.. Why??

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in saying that the potential energy increases as positive and negative charges are being separated and so work must be done by an external force.
So work done by the external force is positive.

On the other hand the work done by the system (capacitor) is negative.

So you need to define the symbols that you use in your equation $W=-\Delta U$.

Comment: Thanks! Wait so if work is -  delta U for everyone how is the external work positive?

Comment: @DZD All I did was reproduce the equation stated in the question and then asked for the symbols used in that equation to be defined.  I am sure that the potential energy of the system (capacitor) increases when the plates are separated and work is done by an external force to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The force separating the plates is in the same direction as the displacement so it is positive. That is probably what the teacher meant. The electromagnetic force between the plates was doing negative work since the force was opposite to the displacement - the energy stored by the capacitor increased rather than decreased.

You can compare that with lifting an object. You do positive work when lifting an object but gravity does negative work.

Answer (score 0):

$W=-U$ is defined for the same system you are working on, meaning it is correct for the capacitor system only, not the capacitor-external agency system. Now, you can see how it works: by considering the agencies separately, it holds.